# Raising a ValueError in a function

Tags: python, exception, valueerror

I have written this code and when I submit to my MOOC, it produces an error, but everything is fine in my terminal?

```
def suggest(product_idea):
    return product_idea + "inator"

try:
    product_idea = input("What is your product idea? ")
    if len(product_idea) <= 3: #to catch the exception of people trying to use LESS THAN 3 characters
        raise ValueError("Your product Idea is too short. Please re-submit with more than 3 characters.") #raise is used here to capture the error
except ValueError as err: #this is to handle the error from line 8
        print("Oh no! That's not a valid value. Try again...")
        print("({})".format(err)) #this is to handle the error from line 8
else:
        print("Great idea!")
```

Here is the error I get from the MOOC (Treehouse):

```
Bummer: Oh no, there were 2 problems with your code, check the preview pane for more information
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_exception_not_raised (__main__.TestRaiseExecution)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 23, in test_exception_not_raised
  File "/workdir/utils/challenge.py", line 20, in execute_source
    exec(src)
  File "", line 5, in 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

======================================================================
ERROR: test_exception_raised (__main__.TestRaiseExecution)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 30, in test_exception_raised
  File "/workdir/utils/challenge.py", line 20, in execute_source
    exec(src)
  File "", line 5, in 
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have inserted the 'else' part of the 'if else' statement under the wrong block of code. It belongs under 'Try' in your Try block.

```
    def suggest(product_idea):
        return product_idea + "inator"

    try:
        product_idea = input("What is your product idea? ")
        if len(product_idea) <= 3: #to catch the exception of people trying to use LESS THAN 3 characters
            raise ValueError("Your product Idea is too short. Please re-submit with more than 3 characters.") #raise is used here to capture the error
        else:
            print("Great idea!")

    except ValueError as err: #this is to handle the error from line 8
            print("Oh no! That's not a valid value. Try again...")
    print("({})".format(err)) #this is to handle the error from line 8
```

Also, I created another version of your code where the function you created ,suggest(), is called in the Try block.

```
    def suggest(product_idea):
        print(product_idea + "inator")

    try:
        product_idea = input("What is your product idea? ")
        if len(product_idea) <= 3: #to catch the exception of people trying to use LESS THAN 3 characters
            raise ValueError("Your product Idea is too short. Please re-submit with more than 3 characters.") #raise is used here to capture the error
        else:
            suggest(product_idea)
            print("Great idea!")

    except ValueError as err: #this is to handle the error from line 8
            print("Oh no! That's not a valid value. Try again...")
    print("({})".format(err)) #this is to handle the error from line 8
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

use `raw_input("What is your product idea? ")` instead of `input("What is your product idea? ")`

Comment: The method of input is not the problem. In any case, `input` vs `raw_input` can only cause issues in python 2.6/7.

Comment: or else if  you want to use input function than need to give input as quotes like "hello world" instead of hello world

Comment: @RajanShah This is only an issue when using python 2.x instead of Python 3.x - that's not the issue here